# which is the best way to show, calculate chat duration using react js, socket io?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I am building chat app. react js for frontend and nodejs, mysql for backend. 
I am calculating chat duration from front end, for example, when chat starts, I initiates time from javascript and when chat ends I submit total time to backend through socket emit.

To handle page refresh, I use localstorage to resume time.

Is this the best way to achieve this or it should be handled from backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually its a good idea to update to backend. Since if the internet connection is broken or the window is closed, you'll know.